# React Native custom combobox component moves off screen with user input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Using React Native, I am building my own Combobox component, but every time I type in an input, everything moves off screen. This is what I mean:

[image: No Input]
[image: Some Input]

Here is my code for the LocationComboBox:

```js
export default (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const fetchSearchResults = async (input) => {
    console.log(searchTownsAndStates(input));
  };

  const onChangeText = (text) => {
    setValue(text);
    fetchSearchResults(text);
  };

  const LocationList = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={searchTownsAndStates()}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.town}, ${item.state}`}
        renderItem={({item, key}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={!error ? style.textBoxShell : style.textBoxShellError}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={props.children}
          placeholderTextColor={!error ? colors.white : "#9e0031"}
          style={!error ? style.textBox : style.textBoxError}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          value={value}
        />
        {value && <LocationList />}
      </View>
      <Text style={style.textBoxError}>{error}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  textBox: {
    color: colors.white,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  textBoxError: {
    color: colors.error,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  textBoxShell: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#444742",
    marginHorizontal: "10%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  textBoxShellError: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.error,
    marginHorizontal: "10%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Here is my code for the LocationScreen:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import { View } from "react-native";

import RootContainer from "../../components/RootContainer";
import LocationComboBox from "../../components/LocationComboBox";
import ParagraphTextLabel from "../../components/ParagraphTextLabel";
import PrimaryButton from "../../components/PrimaryButton";
import HeaderTextLabel from "../../components/HeaderTextLabel";
import SignupContext from "./Context/SignupContext";

import style from "./styles/style";

export default ({ navigation }) => {
  const contextData = {
    location: useState(''),
  };

  return (
    <SignupContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      <SignupContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <RootContainer>
            <View style={style.mainPanel}>
              <View style={style.midPanel}>
                <HeaderTextLabel>Where are you?</HeaderTextLabel>
                <View>
                  <LocationComboBox>
                    Enter your location here...
                  </LocationComboBox>
                  <ParagraphTextLabel>
                    You need to set your location so that other users can find
                    you.
                  </ParagraphTextLabel>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={style.lowerPanel}>
                <PrimaryButton onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Religion")}>
                  Next
                </PrimaryButton>
              </View>
            </View>
          </RootContainer>
        )}
      </SignupContext.Consumer>
    </SignupContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

By the way, I already created an algorithm to bring up the search results and the algorithm for that works as intended.